# How much did it cost to refurbish the Launch Complex 39 hardware after an Apollo Saturn V launch?

Tags: launch, launch-site, cost

A launch pad used for a rocket of some 30-35 MNewtons of thrust does not come out of it unscathed. It must be refurbished before it can be used again. How much does that cost? As an indication of such costs, specifically for a Saturn V launch system, how much did it cost to refurbish one of the Launch Complex 39 pads (including the LUT) after an Apollo launch? Answer can be in any-year dollars, but please specify which year. Or, if that information is too far in the past to be resurrected: how much does it cost to refurbish the pad after a Falcon Heavy launch?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's easier to find data on a publicly funded project like Apollo or STS than to get SpaceX to say what their costs are.

Comment: *Moonport* says "Restoration cost an average $200000 and took one month", that's for LC-37 though.